# Is possible install apk from .NET MAUI to android v10.0?

Tags: android, maui

I can't install apk produces by .NET MAUI using .NET6 in my android 10.0 API 29. When i try to install, show me the next message:

[image: Error when install apk]

The minimun version available in MAUI for android is version 12.0 API 31.
Somebody knows how to builds apk using MAUI for android 10.0 version?
According to Microsoft it has compatibility for Android 5.0 or higher but i cant find the way to reach that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do understand the difference between target and minimum. But that is not your main problem.

9 out of 10 times, this error comes from signing issues.
(It is good idea, to write errors in English, and post them as text, not images)

Simply building release APK file, and copying it to the device will not work.
The process of signing includes creating keystore file, and using it in your project build steps.

Very good tutorial can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: I just needed sign my apk after publish. Once signed, all runs ok.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible install apk from .NET MAUI to android v10.0?

Yes, you can run your .net maui project on the android v10.0.

[image]

The **Minimum Target Android Framework** is the minimum andorid version your app can run on. And it's default value is Android 5.0.

You can also add the following code into the /Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33"/>
```

> When i try to install, show me the next message.

There are many problems will cause this error. Such as the apk file is broken, the device is not compatible and so on.

So you can try to debug your project on the android 10.0 emulator or some other devices. And then release it and intall the apk file.